# Using Annotations / Code Generation to in Java Logging System

Tags: java, performance, annotations

I'm trying to augment the functionality of Java logging to be a bit more efficient.  A typical example of logging is something like the following:

```
logger.warn("This is a warning about " + a.toString() + " " + b.toString()
```

This can trivially be made more efficient by adding an if check:

```
if (logger.isWarnEnabled())  {...}
```

The "if" check saves the parameter building and string concatenation.  Of course, adding these "if" statements make the code a bit bloated and messy.  I would like to design something that can replace all logger.info / logger.warn, etc. calls at the point of usage with the version that includes an "if" check.

Any suggestions on some good ways to go about doing this?  I would like to avoid something that is a straight find/replace in the source text itself, as this is error prone.  Maybe something that makes use of annotations and bytecode manipulation?  Those are not things I've worked very extensively with, so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like what is done by Slf4J by default ? http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#typical_usage

Comment: For no more than 2 arguments, SLF4J does exactly this and there's no way to make it any faster. For more arguments, a varargs array gets created, even when logging is off, but this is acceptable as it's way cheaper than creating strings and so many arguments are rather rare.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't know of any simple way of doing what you want.

---

However, I would also recommend that you DON'T TRY to do this using annotation processing, or bytecode rewriting.  Both are complicated, and both mean that the code you execute is different to the code that you wrote.  Both of these will make life hairy for the next guy who has to maintain your code.

I also suggest that you DON'T TRY to apply this optimization using a plain search / replace:

- As you point out, you could make a mistake.
- IMO, you shouldn't replace them all anyway.  (Read on ...)

---

The reality is that adding a guard on a log statement is only a *worthwhile* optimization if the log statement is *likely* to be executed frequently.  So it is a good idea to *think* about where you apply this optimization.  And at the same time, you should think about whether the log statement is worthwhile.  (If your code is full of log statements that would be executed frequently, then the chances are that you would generate excessive logging if the level was set to DEBUG.  You probably want to avoid that.)